# iphone conenct to ubuntu

Tags: iphone, ubuntu, connect

I can connect the iPhone 6 to my Ubuntu. Then i trying to connect iPhone 7 to my Ubuntu will not show up. i can find alot of guide but i can't still not connect to me computer.

Here is my driver installed.

```
libusbmuxd-dev/xenial,now 1.0.10+git20161018-2salbabix27xenial amd64 [installed,automatic]
libusbmuxd4/xenial,now 1.0.10+git20161018-2salbabix27xenial amd64 [installed]
libimobiledevice-dev/xenial,now 1.2.0+git20161018-3salbabix27xenial amd64 [installed]
libimobiledevice6/xenial,now 1.2.0+git20161018-3salbabix27xenial amd64 [installed]
```

> iPhone” could not be found. Perhaps it has recently been deleted

Have some one any ide how i can connect?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of libimobiledevice (the "driver" for iOS on Linux), dating from 2016. That version probably does not support newer iPhone models.

We maintain a package repository with newer versions of libimobiledevice.

Can you try the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:quamotion/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then unplug your device and plug it back in?